# Selenium grid runs out of free slots

Tags: selenium, nunit, specflow

I have a large suite of SpecFlow tests executing against a selenium grid running locally. The grid has a single host configured for max 10 firefox instances. The tests are run from NUnit serially, so I would only expect to require a single session at a time.

However, when approximately half of the test cases have been run, the console window reporting output from the hub starts reporting

> INFO: Node host [url] has no free slots

Why?

All the test cases are associated with a TearDown method that closes and disposes the WebDriver, although I haven't verified that absolutely every test gets to this method without failing.  I would expect a maximum of one session to be active at once. How can I find out what is stopping the host from recycling those sessions?

**edit #1:**

I think I've narrowed down the cause of the issue - it is indeed to do with not closing the WebDriver. There are [AfterScenario] attributes on the teardown methods that are meant to do this, but they only match a subset of scenarios as they have parameters on them. Removing the parameter so that the teardown associates with every scenario fixes the session exhaustion (or seems to) but there are some tests that expect to reacquire an existing session, so I'll have to fix them separately.

A bit of background: This test suite was inherited as part of a 'complete' solution and it's been left untouched and never run since delivery. I'm putting it back into service and have had to discover its quirks as I go - I didn't write any of this. I've had brief encounters with both Selenium and SpecFlow but never used the two together.

Comment: close ur sessions properly..make a check where you are calling driver.quit or driver.close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue turned out to be a facepalm-level fail - mostly in the sense that I didn't spot it. Some logging code was trying to write to a file that wasn't there, the thrown exception bypassed the call to `Dispose()` on the WebDriver, and was then swallowed with no error reporting. Therefore the sessions were hanging around. Removing the logging code fixed the session exhaustion.

Answer (score 1):

Look on the node (remote desktop) and see what is happening on the box. It does sound like your test isn't closing out it's session properly.

Comment: The node is running on my dev machine and I can watch its output in the console. How can I tell from this output whether or not the session is closed?

Comment: Is the browser still open? If not, the session is *probably* closed.

Comment: I certainly don't see ten browsers open when the 'no free slots' message starts appearing. Eventually it does seem to settle down and start executing tests again. This suggests to me that something is timing out and releasing those sessions automatically - it'd be great to know which bits of code were orphaning them

Comment: So, if you are running your tests serially, you'll only see a single test running at a time. You shouldn't see more than one. How many tests do you have? If you have about 20, I'm guessing it's never getting closed.

Comment: **Lots**. 1662 cases, in ~100 scenarios. Might have narrowed down the cause now; see my edit.

Comment: Ah, I realize this advice will likely fall on deaf ears, but my advice would be to *not* ever reuse sessions across tests for a host of reasons. It's a death trap. You have to do lots of finagling to get things to open and close correctly and you always stand the chance of polluting one session with another. Worst case, I would try to only reuse sessions within a particular class of tests so a developer would know without having to read through source code to figure out whether or not they are going to end up with a clean session or not. But, I understand the motivation - speed, etc...